# Is there a simple way to execute a SQL script in Jboss?

Tags: jboss, redhat, teiid

I want to simple execute a Sql script against a Database in Jboss. I created a Teiid project with the datasource pointing to the source table. I don't need any field mapping, just the script execution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use Teiid? If you have a data source then you can connect to it and issue any SQL statement over the JDBC connection.

Comment: Hello Ramesh, thanks for the tip, I'm new to Jboss, if you know some example that can help me with this task...thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I tried Teiid because I needed to open a Flat File and copy this data to an actual table. If there is a cleaner way to do this, I would appreciate your help.